# How to remove the "," comma which i am getting before a column value after joining data from 2 files

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to run a pig script which picks data from 2 separate strings (string1, string2). And then using tokenize to separate them and later

Input:

```
String1 ="cow moon"; 
string2 ="cow over moon"
```

Expected Output:

```
cow, doc1
cow, doc2
over, doc1
moon, doc1
moon, doc1
```

Script:

```
tokenised_words1 = FOREACH stopWord1 GENERATE TOKENIZE(string1);

data1 = FOREACH tokenised_words1  GENERATE FLATTEN($0);

tokenised_words2 = FOREACH stopWord2 GENERATE TOKENIZE(string2);

data2 = FOREACH tokenised_words2  GENERATE FLATTEN($0);

corres_word_presentin_doc1 = FOREACH data1 GENERATE $0, 'doc1';

corres_word_presentin_doc2 = FOREACH data2 GENERATE $0,' doc2';

output_data = JOIN corres_word_presentin_doc1 BY ($0,$1) FULL OUTER,corres_word_presentin_doc2 BY ($0,$1);

dump output_data;
```

after that i am getting the output like below.

Current Output:

```
(cow,string1,,)
(,,cow, string2)
(,,moon, string1)
(moon,string1,,)
(,,over, string2)
```

Why i am getting extra commas in those values?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Pig hasn't had a release in 4 years, are you sure it's the right tool for your problem? You'll probably find Apache Spark much easier to work with.

Comment: @BenWatson Yup Spark would be much easier. I have started with hadoop. I am currently at learning stage.
But hope you understood my question.
Guess i know why i have those comma, since i am trying to do join on first column using FULL OUTER join, if doesn't find in the string2 or vice versa if word not found in string 1, it is printing it as null value.

Comment: Note: Your output does not say anything about `doc1` or `doc2`. Did you want to filter out / rename `string1` and `string2`? You can also use filter to remove empty strings... Also, you want union between two tuples, not "join" since you have no shared keys